# PyCharm: Unable to Move Refactor static methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, refactoring, pycharm

(Environment: PyCharm 5.0.2, interepreter: Python 2.7 bundled with OSX 10.10)

Hey folks,

I've been unable to figure out how to get PyCharm to let me do a Move Refactor on a static method. Is this supported? I couldn't find any documentation indicating that it is not.

### Specific behavior

I started up a brand new workspace and put this into a file.

```
class MyGreatDemonstratorClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def some_static_method():
        print "static hey"

    @classmethod
    def some_class_method(cls):
        print "class hey"

    def some_instance_method(self):
        print "instance hey"


def unbound_method():
    print "unbound hey"
```

1. I right click on `some_static_method`, hover over "Refactor", click "Move"
2. Red text pops up saying "Cannot perform refactoring using selected element(s)" ([img](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sh98743py1b8tlc/Screenshot%202015-12-21%2014.43.42.png?dl=0))
3. (The same applies for `some_class_method` and `some_instance_method`, though that makes sense to me; refactoring a bound method is hard.)
4. Repeat #1 on `unbound_method`, it should work.

### So my question is

- Is refactoring an @staticmethod supported in PyCharm?
- If not, what is the recommended way to do it? Rope?

Comment: I have the same problem with instance methods and get the same result. Seems like a broader problem with moving methods, not just static ones.

Comment: To add to the question, I tried selecting the whole method, just the name, from "def" up to the name and also the whole declaration line. In all that cases the result was the same "Cannot perform refactoring on selected element(s)".

Comment: I'm hitting this too. Seems like a bug; here's a relevant issue in the bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21871. Voting there seems to affect prioritization of their sprints, so it's worth doing if this still affects you.

Comment: @Symmetric: Your link now says this feature is not supported, and the documentation is wrong when saying it is (though they talk about a static method only). I wonder what is the difficulty, if any, to implement such refactoring. Also [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34363). Still true in 2019!